# Rails SQL query builder... Or ActiveRecord query builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

I need to run sql query like

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id != ' + self.id.to_s + ' AND id NOT IN (SELECT artner_id FROM encounters WHERE user_id = ' + self.id.to_s + ')'
sql += ' AND id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM encounters WHERE partner_id = ' + self.id.to_s + ' AND predisposition = ' + Encounter::Negative.to_s + ')'
sql += ' AND cfg_sex = ' + self.sex.to_s + ' AND cfg_country = ' + self.country.to_s + ' AND cfg_city = ' + self.city.to_s
sql += ' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1'
```

It can be executed by AR.find_by_sql, but the code before is bad readable.
Are there any query builder, which can build that query?

For example, Kohana (it is PHP framework, I am php developer, but I want to change that kid-language to ruby/rails) have a query builder, which works like this:

```
$sql = DB::select('*')->from('users');
$sql->where('id', 'NOT_IN', DB::expr('SELECT partner_id FROM encounters WHERE user_id = '.$user->id));
$sql->where('id', 'NOT_IN', DB::expr('SELECT user_id FROM encounters WHERE partner_id = '.$user->id.' AND predisposition = '.Encounter::Negative));
....
etc
...
```

Query which was builded with query builder like a Kohana query builder is more readable and understandable.

Are there any gem to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem. It **extends** AR with blocks and makes very complicated queries with ease.

Just few features:

```
# not_in == cool! )
Product.where{id.not_in LineItem.select{product_id}}
# SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" NOT IN 
# (SELECT "line_items"."product_id" FROM "line_items" )

# outer joins on pure Ruby:
LineItem.joins{product.outer}
# LineItem Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" 
# LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "line_items"."product_id"

# calcs, aliasing:
Product.select{[avg(price).as(middle)]}
# SELECT avg("products"."price") AS middle FROM "products"

# comparison
Product.where{id != 100500}
Product.where{price<10}

# logical OR
Product.where{(price<10) | (title.like '%rails%')}
# SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (("products"."price" < 10 OR
# "products"."title" LIKE '%rails%'))

# xxx_any feature (also available xxx_all)
Product.where{title.like_any %w[%ruby% %rails%]}
# SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (("products"."title" LIKE '%ruby%' OR 
# "products"."title" LIKE '%rails%'))
```

Note the using blocks: `{...}` here aren't hashes. Also note the absence of symbols.

**If you decide to pick it, read the section that starts with "This carries with it an important implication"**

Answer (score 4):

There's a ruby library that utilizes relational algebra. It is called [ARel](https://github.com/rails/arel). If you are using Rails 3.x, then you already have.

```
ids   = Partner.where(user_id: self.id).pluck(:partner_id) << self.id
users = User.where("id NOT IN #{ ids.join(',') }")
```

Comment: Can it paste db expressions in query, to build query like 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id != ' + self.id.to_s + ' AND id NOT IN (SELECT artner_id FROM encounters WHERE user_id = ' + self.id.to_s + ')'?

Comment: why not do a left join in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the same query cast into rails AREL terms. It's not pretty yet -- it's a complicated query in general.

```
User.where("id = ? AND "
           "id NOT IN (SELECT artner_id FROM encounters WHERE user_id = ?) AND " +  
           "id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM encounters WHERE partner_id = ? AND predisposition = ? ) AND " + 
            "cfg_sex = ? AND cfg_country = ? AND cfg_city = ?)", 
            self.id, self.id, self.id, Encounter::Negative, 
            self.sex, self.country, self.city).order(" rand() ").limit(1)
```

(I've not tested this, so it's possible there could be typo's in it.)

I'd recommend a couple things:

When you have complex where clauses they can be chained together and AREL will put them back together generally pretty well. This allows you to use scopes in your model classes and chain them together.

For example, you could do this:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.in_city_state_country(city, state, country)
    where("cfg_sex = ? AND cfg_country = ? AND cfg_city = ?", city, state, country)
  end

  def self.is_of_sex(sex)
    where("cfg_sex = ?", sex)
  end
end
```

Then you could rewrite these portions of the query this way:

```
User.is_of_sex(user.sex).in_city_state_country(user.city, user.state, user.country)
```

and so on.

Breaking the queries down into smaller parts also makes it easier to test specific pieces of it with your rspecs. It results in more modular, maintainable code.

For more details, check out the [Rails Guide - Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)