# How to search for multiple strings in a database table column?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2.2 and MySQL. I am searching by user name (for instances, `John`, `Anthony`, `Mark`) a database table column this way:

```
# User controller
User.search_by_name(params[:search]).order(:name)

# User model
def self.search_by_name(search)
  if search
    where('users.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

However, since a name can be composed from two or more strings (for instances, `John Henry` or `Henry John`, `Anthony Maria` or `Maria Anthony`, `Mark Alfred` or `Alfred Mark`), *I would like to search users also when in the `params[:search]` are provided more than one name*. I tried to use

```
def self.search_by_name(search)
  if search
    search.split(' ').each do |string|
      where('users.name LIKE ?', "%#{string}%")
    end
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

but I get the following error (for instance, given I am searching for `John Henry`):

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `order' for ["John", "Henry"]:Array).
```

*How can I properly search for multiple names?*

Comment: If you have "John Henry" in the database and someone searches for "John", should it match? What if the name is "Mark Anthony" and someone searches for "Maria Anthony"?

Comment: @mu is too short - **a)** *If you have "John Henry" in the database and someone searches for "John", should it match?* Yes, it should. **b)** *What if the name is "Mark Anthony" and someone searches for "Maria Anthony"?* In this case it should return records matching "Maria" *or* "Anthony" (so, in your example, it should include "Mark Anthony") but records should be *ordered* considering the matching "level" (that is, records should be ordered by those that match "better" with "Maria Anthony" - I don't know if it is possible by using directly a MySQL query).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10551561/1322562. The last feature in the example -- `like_any` has to be your case. You can use something like: `names=params[:search].split; @users=User.where{name.like_any(names)}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally think you should do one of the following,

### Mysql full text search:

http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

### SphinxSearch:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/

- I recommend sphinxsearch since I use it with various cool features
  built in with it.
- Support for sphinx is amazing too!

Answer (score 1):

Using the squeel gem.

```
def self.search_by_name(search)
  if search
    where(name.like_any search.split)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Note that this will NOT order by matching level. For that you need a search-engine implementation, like gems for sphinx, solr, xapian

also note that your original use of each is incorrent since you meant to 'OR' the conditions. If you do not mind to issue as many db queries as search terms you could even fake the match level ordering.

```
def self.search_by_name(search)
  if search
    results = search.split.map do |string|
      where('users.name LIKE ?', "%#{string}%").all
    end.flatten
    ids = results.map(&:id)
    # desc order by count of matches
    ordered_results = results.uniq.order { |result| -ids.count(result.id) }
  else
    scoped.all
  end
end
```

This is not an Arel relation that can be further scoped but a plain array though.
Note the 'all' call, so do not even attempt this on a big db.
Also note that this will not order 'a b' above 'b a' if search is 'a b' etc.
So I'm kinda just having fun.