# How to combine two scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, rails-activerecord

I have a tag feed and a friend feed. 
I want to combine these two and build the ultimate "all" feed.

For friend feed:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :friendfeed, lambda{|x| followed_by}

  def self.followed_by(user)
    where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", user.watched_ids, user.id)
  end
end
```

For tag feed:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :tagfeed, lambda{|x| infatuated_with}

  def self.infatuated_with(user)
    joins(:attachments).where("attachments.tag_id IN (?)", user.tags).select("DISTINCT pages.*")
  end
end
```

And I would call something like this from the controller (I'm using Kaminari gem for pagination):

```
@tag_feed = Post.tagfeed(current_user).page(params[:page]).per(21)
@friend_feed = Post.friendfeed(current_user).page(params[:page]).per(21)
```

Now I want to have a universal feed, but I'm lost. Scopes are meant for narrowing down, but in this case I'm trying to do an OR operation. Doing stuff like

```
@mother_of_all_feed = @tag_feed + @friend_feed
```

would be redundant, and I wouldn't be able to control the number of posts appearing on a single page. How can I go about doing this? Thanks!

By the way, for tags I have association set up like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
  has_many :tags, :through => :attachments
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
  has_many :posts, :through => :attachments
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question. I think I figured out a way.

```
where("pages.id IN (?) OR pages.id IN (?)",
  Page.where(
      "user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?",
      user.watched_ids, user.id
  ),
  Page
    .joins(:attachments)
    .where("attachments.tag_id IN (?)", user.tags)
    .select("DISTINCT pages.*")
)
```

It seems to be working so far, hope this is it!

Comment: Are you satisfied with its performance? Looks like you get 4-5 queries here. It seems you have two options: write raw SQL-query or use my favorite gem squeel. It allows to perform OR and supports `in` feature that leads to nested SQL query. Take a look: https://github.com/ernie/squeel. I tried to "advertise" it few times, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10551561/1322562, but only few people liked it. I'm wondering why. With squeel you can reuse your scopes and build complex query in pure Ruby, like: `Product.where{(id.in Product.ruby)|(id.in Product.rails)}` via single(!!!) SQL query!

Comment: Not satisfied, but I was just prototyping so it's OK. I will take a look at squeel. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

There's a rails pull request for this feature (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9052), but in the meantime, some one has created a monkey patch that you can include in your initializers that will allow you to or scopes and where clauses in one query and still give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/250eaaceef234dd8971b

With that, you'd be able to OR your scopes like this

```
Post.tagfeed(current_user).or.friendfeed(current_user)
```

or write a new scope

```
scope :mother_of_all_feed, lambda{|user| tagfeed(user).or.friendfeed(user)}
```

Comment: Yes, the `OR` has been added to `ActiveRecord::Relation#or` in Rails 5 - http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-5-features/

Comment: correct way for AR `or`  is `tagfeed(user).or(friendfeed(user))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how I combined two scopes.

```
scope :reconcilable, -> do
  scopes = [
    with_matching_insurance_payment_total,
    with_zero_insurance_payments_and_zero_amount
  ]

  where('id in (?)', scopes.flatten.map(&:id))
end
```

Comment: This does not seem very effective to me because several database queries are triggered. With a current Rail version, one database query should suffice.