# Many to Many NOT in

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a multi-table join that has a NOT IN component. Tables are

Post -> Term Relationship -> Term

```
Post
  has_many :term_relationships
  has_many :terms, :through => :term_relationships

TermRelationship
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :term

Term
  has_many :term_relationships
  has_many :posts, :through => :term_relationships
```

The goal is to get all posts *except* for those in "featured" let's say. My current query would looks like:

```
WpPost.includes(:terms).where("terms.term NOT IN (?)", ["featured"])
```

This works great if the only term that it has attached is "featured". If the post belongs to "featured" and "awesome" it will still show because of "awesome".

Anyway to exclude a row entirely? Will it require a subquery? And if it does, how would I go about doing that in rails?

Thanks all!
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misuse the `includes`. It's for eager loading, not for joining!

But you're right about the approach. It can be used in your case. But Rails won't issue nested request for `NOT IN (?)` even if it would be logical. You'll get 2 queries instead (you'll get `NOT IN (id1, id2....,)` instead of `NOT IN (SELECT ....)`).

So I would recommend you to use [the squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel):

regular AR code (can also be prettified with squeel):

```
featured_posts = WpPost.joins(:terms).where(terms:{term: ['featured']}).uniq
```

and then use the sqeel's power:

```
WpPost.where{id.not_in featured_posts}
```

(`in` and `not_in` are also aliased as `>>` and `<<` but I didn't want to scary anybody)

**Note the using blocks and absence of symbols.**

---

Some measurements based on [Chinook Database](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Home) under SQLite:

```
> Track.all
  Track Load (35.0ms)  SELECT "Track".* FROM "Track"
```

Relation with `joins` and `like`:

```
oldie = Track.joins{playlists}.where{playlists.name.like_any %w[%classic% %90%]}
```

Here's `NOT IN`:

```
> Track.where{trackId.not_in oldie}.all
  Track Load (37.5ms)  SELECT "Track".* FROM "Track" WHERE "Track"."trackId" 
  NOT IN (SELECT "Track"."TrackId" FROM "Track" INNER JOIN "PlaylistTrack" ON
    "PlaylistTrack"."TrackId" = "Track"."TrackId" INNER JOIN "Playlist" ON 
    "Playlist"."PlaylistId" = "PlaylistTrack"."PlaylistId"
     WHERE (("Playlist"."name" LIKE '%classic%' OR "Playlist"."name" LIKE '%90%')))
```

FYI:

```
Track.where{trackId.not_in oldie}.count # => 1971
Track.count # => 3503
# join table:
PlaylistTrack.count # => 8715
```

**Conclusion:** I don't see the overhead caused by `NOT IN`. 35.0 vs 37.5 isn't noticeable difference. Few times 35.0 became 37.5 and vice verse.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Squeel looks awesome. How would I do @DanneManne's suggestion of the outerleft join in Squeel? The `NOT IN` proves to be slow. 140ms vs 2ms. It looks like I'm supposed to write it `Post.joins{terms.outer}....` but I don't understand where to specify `terms.term = "featured"`. Any further help would be much appreciated

Comment: `Post.joins{terms.outer}.where{terms.term=='featured'}`. Here's http://stackoverflow.com/a/10551561/1322562 my other answer with some examples.

Comment: Thanks @jdoe. If I'm not mistaken that allows `WHERE terms.term = "featured"`, I'm looking for @DanneManne's `LEFT OUTER JOIN terms ON term_relationships.term_id = terms.id AND terms.term = ?"`. According to Squeel's doc it looks like it would be `Post.joins{terms(featured).outer}...`, but obviously there is magic happening there. Thanks, Squeel is awesome btw.

Comment: Oh, that. I didn't understand your intention. I'm afraid conditions in `ON` is too rare case to be covered by the "magic". But I'm still wondering how did you measure 140 ms vs 2 ms. Are you sure about that? Everything's fine with your indexes?

Comment: Thanks @jdoe. If I pull out the NOT IN (?) portion the time drops to 2ms. If I add it in the query skyrockets to 140ms and that is regardless of number of items in the NOT IN. Obviously, it is not using the index to build NOT IN. I read NOT EXISTS uses the index while NOT IN notoriously skips indicies. Thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my answer with my simple measurements based on publicly available DB-sample Chinook. Check if you build `NOT IN` the same way and see if your resulting SQL looks like the one I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do an OUTER JOIN and put the featured argument there. Then you just select all posts where no term was joined. I don't know any way of doing it in a plain "Rails way" but with some extra SQL you could do it like this:

```
Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN term_relationships ON posts.id = term_relationships.post_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN terms ON term_relationships.term_id = terms.id AND terms.term = ?", "featured").
     where("terms.id IS NULL")
```